# Prevent NSIS "error opening file for writing"

Tags: installation, nsis

On some computers the antivirus while the installation files are being copied blocks the file and the installer throws the error "Error opening file for writing filename.extension" is there any way to solve this? That before launching the exception to the user, try again? If the user clicks retry it works, but I want to avoid it to the user.

My Nsis code to include files.

```
File /r /x *.tlb "${MyPath}"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there no is way to work around this when using `/r` or wildcards with `File`.

In theory you could wrap single `File` commands in a macro that first calls `FileOpen` in a loop but there is no way to know how many retries you would need and if you need a `Sleep` etc.

Anti-Virus software is supposed to be transparent to normal applications. The best way to deal with this is to file a bug report with the vendor and to publicly name-and-shame them.

Comment: Thanks! It was what I imagined from what I have been reading. I have contacted the antivirus but in the end new antivirus programs appear and you can not be contacting all of them.